# How to login Separately in each blog?

Tags: multisite

I am creating multiple WordPress sites. When I log in to my main site then I will be logged in automatically in all the blogs that I created in my WordPress Multisite instance. So, I want to separate the log-in for each blog.

Answer (score -2):

Try using anonymous windows in your browser or separate log ins. For e.g. I'm using Chrome and I can set up different browser accounts with different emails and passwords.
It's kind of a cheat-solution, but it works fine:)

Comment: How does using a separate window help when logging in logs you in with all subpages?

Comment: You need to use anonymous window and log in form there. Or as I mentioned before - create different log ins in chrome browser (e.g.: I have one with my work email and one for private each with different log in. They don't interfere.)